# Boolean will not change to false

Tags: php

When a user sells an item, it gives money and makes it false, but this program is giving money but will not set the boolean to false.

```
<? require("Left.php"); ?>
<html>
    <img src="images/X100.png" style="width:304px;height:228px">
    <p>The X100 is a miner that was designed in 1980, it is cheap and horrible, it will yeild little gold and uses lots of fuel</p>
    <table width="" height="1" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Fuel usage
            <td>50</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="" height="1" border="1" align="center">
        <td>

            Max gold per ton
            <td>3</td>
        </td>
    </table>
    <table width="" height="1" border="1" align="center">
        <td>
            Price
            <td>6000 money</td>
        </td>
    </table>
    <form method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="buy" id="buy" value="buy">
</form>

<? if($ownstarter == true){
    echo 'Sell your X100 for 3000 money';
    echo "<form method='post' > <input type='submit' name='Sell' id='Sell' value='Sell'> </form>";
}?>
</form>
</html>
<?
 if (isset($_POST['buy']) and $money >= 6000 and $ownstarter == false) {
    $money = $money - 6000;
    $ownstarter = true;
} elseif ($money <= 6000 and $ownstarter == false) {
    echo "You cannot afford this! ";
} elseif($ownstarter == true) {
    echo "You already own this item!";

 }
if(isset($_POST['Sell'])){
    $money = $money + 3000;
    $ownstarter = null;
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ownstarter=$ownstarter WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=$money WHERE id='$id'");
 ?>
 <? require("Right.php"); ?>
```

In more detail, if the user owns it, a button with an option saying "Sell" and if the user clicks the button, it gives them 5000 money and it sets ownstarter to false. But it wont set it to false. (I also tired setting it to null and it wont work too) It does give the money but does not set it to false so the button does not go away. Heres a picture of it if it helps http://puu.sh/cC7Kx/69c55ce1dc.jpg

Edit: ok so i added or `die(mysql_error());` to the query and I got this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='3029'' at line 1. but the x200 page has almost the exact same code (I did not add the sell part to it yet) and it works without any error.
X200

```
<? require("Left.php"); ?>
<html>
    <img src="images/X200.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px">
    <p>The X100 miner is a more efficient miner than the X100 miner, that being said, the X200 will still use alot of fuel for little gold. </p>
    <table width="" height="1" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Fuel usage
            <td>70</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="" height="1" border="1" align="center">
        <td>
            Max gold per ton
            <td>5</td>
        </td>
    </table>
    <table width="" height="1" border="1" align="center">
        <td>
            Price
            <td>1 point</td>
        </td>
    </table>
    <form method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="buy" id="buy" value="buy">
</form>
</html>
<?
 if (isset($_POST['buy']) and $points >= 1 and $ownminer1000 == false) {
    $ownminer1000 = true;
    $points = $points - 1;
 }elseif($points < 1 and $ownminer1000 == false){
    echo "You cannot afford this item!";
 }elseif($ownminer1000){
    echo "You already have this item!";
 }
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ownminer1000=$ownminer1000 WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=$points WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
 <? require("Right.php"); ?>
```

Comment: You are checking for the value of `$ownstarter` up above where you change it. Is that where you mean?

Comment: Instead you should use `$ownstarter = 0` and `$ownstarter = 1` for `false/true`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I did do that, read my edit.

Comment: And please do **not use** `mysql_*`, these functions are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

The fact that you are using PHP booleans `true/false` for the value of `$ownerminer1000` and passing them unquoted into a MySQL query is causing a small problem.

When PHP casts the boolean `true` to a string (as it must do in the query), it substitutes the string `1`. Your query for `true` works, because it expands to:

```
SET ownminer1000=1 WHERE id='xxx'
```

When the value of `$ownerminer1000` is false though, PHP casts the `false` to an *empty string*. The result is that your query looks like:

```
SET ownminer1000= WHERE id='xxx'
---------------^^^
```

This stuff is detailed in [PHP's famous/infamous type juggling rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

#### The simplest fix:

That is syntactically invalid. If you want to continue using booleans for that variable, you will need to convert it just before passing it to MySQL.  You can most easily do that by casting it to an integer first.

```
// true becomes 1, false becomes 0
$ownerminer1000 = intval($ownerminer1000);
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ownminer1000=$ownminer1000 WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now the query is syntactically valid and will succeed for false values.

I notice another thing - you are performing two separate `UPDATE` statements against the same table with the same `$id`. You can safely then combine them into one, with multiple `field=value` pairs in the `SET` clause.

```
// Update points and ownerminer1000 at the same time
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=$points, ownminer1000=$ownminer1000 WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

#### Deprecation warning:

Standard disclaimer applies on the use of the `mysql_*()` functions. They were deprecated in PHP 5.5 more than a year ago and should *not* be used for new code. Instead, now is the time to begin learning to use PDO or MySQLi.  Both are newer APIs and both support prepared statements, which will improve the security of your queries.  We cannot see the origin of the variables `$money, $points, $id` above, but if they derive from user input they could be vulnerable to SQL injection.

This [PDO tutorial for MySQL developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is quite good, and frames the use of PDO in context of the old `mysql_*()` functions. Most important is to begin learning to use [`prepare()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).  Your problem today could have been avoided if preparing a statement with a bound placeholder value instead of the boolean variable.